# Problema con Conjunto de anuncios y conversiones personalizadas de Facebook

Tags: eventos, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

**Contextualizo:**

Manejo de una tienda virtual con finalización de compra en botón de WhatsApp, dicha tienda posee subdominios, los cuales manejan el mismo producto, pero cada una de posee ellas un **direccionamiento a WhatsApp distinto (números diferentes)**, pues tiene asesores de ventas diferentes en cada una de ellas.

Al momento de realizar las campañas para el dominio y los sub dominios, si se crea un conjunto de anuncios, se elige el pixel y como evento de conversión **"compras"** y si se segmenta por ejemplo a nivel Colombia y por lo menos, un anuncio por cada tienda, Facebook va a dar el mejor rendimiento a uno de los anuncios y por ende a una de las tiendas oa varias, pero esto dejaría por fuera a las otras, pues precisamente lo que esto busca es ver cual de todas da una mejor entrega...

Lo sería recomendable crear un conjunto de anuncios por cada tienda y uno o varios anuncios también por cada tienda. pero al configurar el evento de conversión y colocar en cada uno de ellos "compras" que es lo que se necesita, Facebook emite varios errores, indicando de una forma u otra que **la entrega no es efectiva porque ya hay anuncios con el mismo evento** de y que conversión de deben o ampliar presupuestos o mejorar la segmentación y por ende uno o varios conjuntos de anuncios, no se entregan adecuadamente, lo que se traduce en **pocos clientes y pocas ventas**.

Para dar solución, cree diferentes conjuntos de anuncios por cada tienda ya su vez, una **segmentación diferente**, principalmente en cuanto a ciudades diferentes en cada uno de ellos, para que Facebook no le de prioridad a uno en específico, pues lo lógico seria que al segmentarse diferente, llegar a públicos diferentes sin afectar el rendimiento, y además, **crear unas conversiones personalizadas enfocadas en enlaces con palabras o contenido clave, como por ejemplo, los números de WhatsApp**, ya que cada uno es distinto y puede ayudar a su diferenciación, para que estas se coloquen en lugar de "compras" pues de hacerlo, Facebook sigue arrojando el mismo error inicial.

No obstante ya pesar de todo esto, **las conversiones personalizadas no se activan** y la campaña que sigue avanzando "correctamente" es la del dominio principal, lo cual produce que los subdominios no tengan ventas y se pierdan prácticamente el dinero invertido en publicidad.

Se que el texto es largo y puede ser un poco confuso, por ello pido disculpas, pero es necesario contextualizar para poder comprender el problema de fondo...

¿Alguien ha tenido un problema similar ya sea con **las conversiones personalizadas, los eventos o los conjuntos de anuncios** o puede ayudarme a analizar de forma apropiada este inconveniente? ¡todos los aportes serán de gran ayuda!